# java 4 decimal place for binary

Tags: java

how can i make sure that the converted binary from int is displayed in 4,8,12... decimal place?

like

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
```

Pls advice..

```
public int binary(int n)
{

if (add > count)
{
    System.out.println("break");
    return 0;
}
else
{

    sb=Integer.toBinaryString(add);
    num = Integer.parseInt(sb);
    add++;
}
while (sb.length()%2==0)

{   temp = sb;
    sb = "";
    sb = "0" + temp;
}
    System.out.println(sb);
    return binary(add);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pad zeros ?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking here

Comment: the result display for dec 0 in binary is "0", i would like it to be in "0000"....so like dec 12 in binary it display "00011000" instead of "1100"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(yourInt);
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length() % 4; i++) {
            s = "0" + s;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is Big-Endian so you can be sure that your code will run the same way on all architectures...
Check this out, maybe is of any help: http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler this way. Make sure the value is exactly five bits long and drop the most-significant bit.

```
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(n & 0xF | 0x10).substring(1);
```